# Analytic continuation of $\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^{2k}}{2k+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the maximal analyticity domain for 
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^{2k}}{2k+1}.$$

**Attempt**

We rewrite $\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^{2k}}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{z}[log(1-z)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{z^{2k}}{k} ]=\frac{1}{2z}[log(1-z)-log(1+z)].$

The $\pm 1$ are branch points by circling around them. At infinity we look at $\frac{1}{z}$ to get

$$\frac{z}{2}[log(z-1)-log(1+z)]=\frac{re^{i\theta}}{2}[log(z-1)-log(1+z)].$$

So by circling around zero we return to same value, thus no branch point there. Therefore, the domain is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$.

Any mistakes?